# If X and Y are independent exponential random variables with pdf $f(x) = 0.5e^{-0.5x}, x\geq 0$, find $P(X>1, Y>4)$

Tags: probability-distributions

My thinking:

$\int_4^\infty\int_1^\infty 0.5e^{(-0.5x)} \,dxdy= $ $\int_4^\infty e^{-0.5} dy $ but when I integrate this I get $e^{-0.5}y\Biggr|_{4}^{\infty}$ which equals $\infty$ what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The joint PDF is $f(x) f(y)$, not just $f(x)$.

Comment: what would f(y) be then. It's not given in the problem?

Comment: The wording is ambiguous, but I think the problem is implying that $Y$ has the same distribution as $X$.

Comment: It does! Thank you so much!